# JButton does not change icon when pressed memory game

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make my own simple memory game and I'm having a JPanel which implements ActionListener interface and contains some Tiles that inherits from JButton. Almost everything works fine except for the fact that button being clicked as the second, does not change its icon as it should do. However when I click two tiles that match they remain flipped and its ok. When I click 1st button it flips over and the second pressed tile provided that its not a matching one behaves like a button without ActionListener added. I thought about fixing that problem with PropertyChangeListener but can't figure out how.

This is method in my JPanel :

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        Tile tile = (Tile)e.getSource();

        if(tilesFlipped < 2 ){
            tile.flip();
            flippedTiles[tilesFlipped++] = tile;

            if(tilesFlipped == 1){
                return;
            }

            if(flippedTiles[0].equals(flippedTiles[1])){
                tilesFlipped = 0;
                return;

            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                        flippedTiles[i].flipBack();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                }   
            }
            tilesFlipped = 0;
        } 

    }
```

And this is my Tile class :

```
private class Tile extends JButton {
    String photoPath;
    ImageIcon photo;

    Tile(int i){
        photoPath = String.format("/home/stn/Desktop/p/9-%d.jpg", i);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        this.photo = new ImageIcon(photoPath);
    }

    public void flip(){
        this.setIcon(photo);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void flipBack(){
        this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        this.setIcon(null);

    }

    public String getPhotoPath(){
        return photoPath;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return o instanceof Tile && ((Tile)o).getPhotoPath().equals(photoPath);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return photoPath.hashCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like tilesFlipped is always going to be 0- we don't have all of the code here but this looks like an error.

Comment: @dbillz tilesFlipped is 0 when the game starts and then seems to work fine ( I haven't prevented the situation when pressed button equals to lastly clicked one, but anyway changing button icon should work)

Comment: UPDATE, problem is almost for sure caused by Thread.sleep() method but I have no idea why and how to solve this issue. What could be the best alternative for Thread.sleep() ?

Comment: Why are you sleeping for a second there? What are you trying to accomplish? Also may want to scrap this question and make a new one because nobody but me probably saw that.

Comment: @dbillz I'm trying to make both flipped tiles flip back after that time as it is in decent memory game :)

Comment: Maybe mark the time when they were flipped over, and in your main logic see if the current time - that time is high enough to flip back? That would make this work but wouldn't be a great solution for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep(...)`. Understand that `Thread.sleep(...)` puts the current thread to sleep, here the Swing **Event Dispatch Thread** or **EDT**, and this will put your entire GUI to sleep, freezing your application. A Swing Timer will do one or repeated actions without tying up the EDT. For example:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Tile tile = (Tile) e.getSource();

    if (tilesFlipped < 2) {
       tile.flip();
       flippedTiles[tilesFlipped++] = tile;

       if (tilesFlipped == 1) {
          return;
       }

       if (flippedTiles[0].equals(flippedTiles[1])) {
          tilesFlipped = 0;
          return;

       } else {
          Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                   flippedTiles[i].flipBack();
                }
                tilesFlipped = 0;
             }
          });
          timer.setRepeats(false);
          timer.start();
       }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem entirely, in fact I at last fixed it with swing timer but the solution wasn't that smooth.